# Rails routing error with long class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, camelcasing

I get confused at Rails pluralising and camelcasing. Especially with my long but clear names.

I have a `User` model and an `Account` model. I also have a `user_to_account_log_history` model and controller for saving transfers between the two. The relationships are setup.

I ran...

```
$ rails generate controller UserToAccountLogHistories
```

...which created the following:

```
# app/controllers/user_to_account_log_histories_controller.rb
class UserToAccountLogHistoriesController < ApplicationController
  # a simple index method
end

# app/models/user_to_account_log_history.rb
class UserToAccountLogHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My routes seems to be in place (`rake routes` output, truncated):

```
user_usertoaccountloghistories GET /users/:user_id/usertoaccountloghistories(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"usertoaccountloghistories"}
```

But I'm getting an `uninitialized constant UsertoaccountloghistoriesController`. Why? I get the feeling it´s the long names camelcasing and pluralising that messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a class called `UserToAccountLogHistoriesController` but no class called `UsertoaccountloghistoriesController` -- note the difference in capitalisation here.

It's not clear from your question exactly how you've defined your route, but I suspect that you've got a route referring to `usertoaccountloghistories` when actually you want to refer to `user_to_account_log_histories`.

In the rails console, observe the following:

```
> "hello_world".camelize
# => "HelloWorld"
> "helloworld".camelize
# => "Helloworld"
```

Comment: Thanks! I entered the route without the underscores.